# Why can't I update my device?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300), my current Android version is 4.0.4.

I am trying to define software updates for it, via the Software Updates screen. (Settings > About).

However, I get "Unable to connect to network" every time. What network is it trying to connect? Can I define it? If so, what should I define it too?

Also, will software updates allow me to update to 4.1.2? If not, how can I?

Can anyone please point to a resource which explains it? (Or even better, answer it here).

If I'm lacking any technical details, please leave a comment and I'll edit my question right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I am too easy with you. 
But just for the fact of helping, were you able to access internet through your mobile? 
If the answer is 'Yes' then there must be a bug with your OS. (There are possibilities for that in one or two devices)
My suggestion is to use 'Kies' from a PC.
Last week only I got to know even GT-I9300 devices are network locked in some countries. A friend of mine's GT-I9100 started asking for Network Unlock code all of a sudden. After a master reset, we noticed some new apps from Vodafone and the default language turned into Spanish or something. 
So I think your GS3 might be trying to access its original operator. 
Or may be some other reason. 
Just try my suggestions if you didn't do already.

Comment: I can access a mobile network. So what do you think I should do? Care to elaborate a bit more about this 'Kies'?

Comment: Samsung Kies is the software for all Samsung's android devices to sync with PC. You can backup your mobile data to PC using Kies. Also you can update your firmware through it, if Samsung made it available for your device. Since, SGS3 has already got the JB update I hope you can give it a try. Download Kies from, http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it refuses the update on mobile network because the download size is pretty big? Try updating while on a wireless network...

Comment: I'm updating it while connected to WiFi. It doesn't work.